# Customize ExtJS Widgets (Skinning)

Tags: extjs4, customization, skinning

I am wondering how can I customize the shape, borders, shadings, colors, effects... etc of existing ExtJS widgets (including the complex ones such as grids)? I want to be able to reuse these and resize them without ruining the new skin (similar to Flex skinning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done it myself but there is a Theming guide to ExtJS. Hope its useful to you:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/theming

Answer (score 1):

As @DmitryB pointed - ExtJs does support themes. I personally like `Slate` http://www.siliconhill.com.au/extjs/index-slate.html for its more modern look than standard "vanilla" theme.

But everything I saw so far on the Internet was basically about changing color palettes and nothing else.

I was looking for something more sophisticated to make for example all controls bigger and more Web2.0 kind of, but didn't find anything unfortunately.

Comment: link is no longer available

Comment: My answer was like 4 years ago :)